# Freecache performance vs sendFile

Tags: go, caching

I am trying to make a small http server for serving images based on there ID. I am using fasthttp for the tcp library and bigcache for caching images in memory. But from my testing fetching the images from bigcache seems to be slower then using fasthttp's sendFile() and I am not sure why this is.

Current code for sending a cached image is

```golang
entry, err := cache.Get(v.(string))
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Image not cached")
    errMsg := (err).Error()
    if strings.Contains(errMsg, "not found") {
        log.Print(err)
        f, _ := os.Open("./test.jpg")
        inBuf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
        cache.Set(v.(string), inBuf)
        ctx.SendFile("./test.jpg")
        return
    }
    log.Print(err)
    return
}
mime := mimetype.Detect(entry)
ctx.SetContentType(mime.String())
ctx.Write(entry)
```

Current code for sending a non cached image is

```golang
ctx.SendFile("./test.jpg")
```

The bigcache config

```golang
config := bigcache.Config{
    Shards:             1024,
    LifeWindow:         100000 * 100000 * 60,
    CleanWindow:        5 * time.Minute,
    MaxEntriesInWindow: 1000 * 10 * 60,
    MaxEntrySize:       500,
    Verbose:            true,
    HardMaxCacheSize:   8192,
    OnRemove:           nil,
    OnRemoveWithReason: nil,
}
```

And here is some loading testing on the endpoints

NOCACHE - FASTHTTP

```
Requests      [total, rate, throughput]         3000, 100.03, 100.03
Duration      [total, attack, wait]             29.992s, 29.99s, 1.644ms
Latencies     [min, mean, 50, 90, 95, 99, max]  979.7µs, 3.15ms, 1.552ms, 1.946ms, 2.216ms,    48.766ms, 218.567ms
Bytes In      [total, mean]                     3714138000, 1238046.00
Bytes Out     [total, mean]                     0, 0.00
Success       [ratio]                           100.00%
Status Codes  [code:count]                      200:3000
Error Set:
```

CACHE - FASTHTTP

```
Requests      [total, rate, throughput]         3000, 100.03, 100.02
Duration      [total, attack, wait]             29.993s, 29.99s, 2.471ms
Latencies     [min, mean, 50, 90, 95, 99, max]  1.308ms, 2.768ms, 2.145ms, 2.707ms, 3.003ms, 3.943ms, 176.941ms
Bytes In      [total, mean]                     3714138000, 1238046.00
Bytes Out     [total, mean]                     0, 0.00
Success       [ratio]                           100.00%
Status Codes  [code:count]                      200:3000
Error Set:
```

Here are some get request timings

```
INFO[0174] GET /nocache/test.jpg - 200 - 794.846µs
INFO[0175] GET /nocache/test.jpg - 200 - 54.408µs
INFO[0183] GET /nocache/test.jpg - 200 - 60.724µs
INFO[0191] GET /cache/1afQJqFd.jpeg - 200 - 677.857µs
INFO[0195] GET /cache/1afQJqFd.jpeg - 200 - 620.761µs
INFO[0195] GET /cache/1afQJqFd.jpeg - 200 - 642.827µs
```

I am not sure why getting the image from bigcache takes longer then reading from the filesystem unless I am misunderstanding how to use bigcache. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If in doubt profile, but my guess is that the string conversions are to blame. It makes little sense to store binary data as strings instead of []byte. That being said, it may turn out that you're not gaining anything by caching, especially in non-realistic benchmarks, such as requesting the same file over and over again. Not every "disk read" actually hits the disk due to filesystem caches, and copying file contents to the network has [excellent support from the kernel](https://golang.org/src/net/sendfile_linux.go).

Comment: Long story short: Think about caches if performance is unacceptable, not before.